# How to check final Apache HTTPD Server configuration values

Tags: apache

I am trying to configure Apache to handle a larger number of requests on Ubuntu 14.04. I have done so by adding the following to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
MaxKeepAliveRequests 500
ServerLimit         20
StartServers         2
MaxRequestWorkers  1000
ThreadsPerChild     50
```

This doesn't seem to be having the desired affect as I am still receiving the error message "server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers settings"

I would like to confirm that I have set the values correctly and that they are not being overridden anywhere else by checking what values Apache actually has for those settings. Is this possible with Apache?

Comment: A few more details, the Server MPM is prefork, the Server Version is  Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I missed that httpd.conf is not included/sourced in apache2.conf by default :-/